# System.debug is giving me null result

Tags: trigger

Can you please spot the error? I am getting 'null' in the System.debug. However, Account has some value in 'Type' field.

```
  trigger UpdateAccountType on Contact (after insert) {
        for(Contact con: Trigger.new){
            System.debug('Account Type' + ' ' + con.Account.Type);

        }

    }
```

Comment: THanks @sfdcfox. I got the resolutions: Why is this trigger finding a null value despite the field being populated? (2 answers)
Trigger after insert null values [duplicate] (1 answer

Comment: Related records - Account in your case - are not automatically populated in triggers. To access the Account Type field, your trigger will have to query the account using the Id `con.AccountId`.